form.is_valid() returns an error which I have not defined
I'm facing a problem using a form in Django. I am trying to create a form in which users (called Intercambiadores in my app) can log in.
In my views.py I have the logic to print which is the error that the user made ( the password is wrong, they are in a "suspendido" state...)
However the problem is that when I try to enter with the correct credentials of an user and form.is_valid() returns false
When I try to print the form.errors.values(), it has an error which I have NOT defined anywhere.
This is the form
class IntercambiadorSesionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Intercambiador
        fields = [
            'dni',
            'contrasenia'
        ]
        labels = {
            'dni' : 'DNI',
            'contrasenia' : 'Contraseña'
        }
        widgets = {
            'dni': forms.TextInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
                'id': 'dni_sesion_intercambiador',
                'name': 'dni_sesion_intercambiador',
                'maxlength': 9,
                'placeholder': 'DNI',
                'required': True,
                'pattern' : '\d*',
                'oninput':"this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '')",
                'style': 'font-size:1.25rem; '
            }),

            'contrasenia' : forms.PasswordInput({
                'class': 'form-control',
                'placeholder': 'Contraseña',
                'required': True,
                'style': 'font-size:1.25rem'
            }),
        }
    
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        dni = cleaned_data.get('dni')
        contrasenia = cleaned_data.get('contrasenia')

        if dni and contrasenia:
            try:
                user = Intercambiador.objects.get(dni=dni)
                if user.contrasenia != contrasenia:
                    raise forms.ValidationError("El DNI y/o contraseña son incorrectos")
                if user.estado == "suspendido":
                    raise forms.ValidationError("Usuario suspendido")
            except Intercambiador.DoesNotExist:
                raise forms.ValidationError("El DNI y/o contraseña son incorrectos")

        return cleaned_data

This would be the model for an user
class Intercambiador(AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager):

    opciones_estado = (('suspendido', 'Suspendido'), ('activo', 'Activo'))

    dni = models.PositiveIntegerField(primary_key=True, editable=True, unique=True)
    contrasenia = models.CharField(max_length=30),
    # something else


This is the function in the views.py file
def iniciar_sesion_inter(request):
    
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        
        diccionario = {
            'dni': request.POST["dni"],
            'contrasenia' : request.POST["contrasenia"]
        }

        form = IntercambiadorSesionForm(diccionario)
        
        if form.is_valid():
            dni = form.cleaned_data['dni']
            user = Intercambiador.objects.get(dni=dni)
            
            if user.estado == "suspendido":
                return render(
                    request,
                    "suspension_mensaje.html",
                    {"fecha": user.fecha_suspension, "nombre_usuario": user.nombre},
                )

            login(request, user)
            return redirect('menu_principal')
        else:
            for error in form.errors.values():
                print(error)
                messages.error(request, error)
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = IntercambiadorSesionForm()
        
    form_registro = IntercambiadorRegistroForm()
    return render(request, "home.html", {"form_inicio_sesion": form_inicio_sesion, "form_registro": form_registro })


If necessary, this is the part of the html file
<form class="navbar-form navbar-right" action="/signin_inter/" method="POST">
      {% csrf_token %}  
      <div class="form-group">
          {{ form_inicio_sesion.dni.label_tag }}
          {{ form_inicio_sesion.dni }}
          {% if form_inicio_sesion.dni.errors %}
              <ul class="errorlist">
                  {% for error in form_inicio_sesion.dni.errors %}
                      <li>{{ error }}</li>
                  {% endfor %}
              </ul>
          {% endif %}
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
          {{ form_inicio_sesion.contrasenia.label_tag }}
          {{ form_inicio_sesion.contrasenia }}
          {% if form_inicio_sesion.contrasenia.errors %}
              <ul class="errorlist">
                  {% for error in form_inicio_sesion.contrasenia.errors %}
                      <li>{{ error }}</li>
                  {% endfor %}
              </ul>
          {% endif %}
      </div>
      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="iniciar_sesion_inter">Iniciar sesión</button>
    </form>

The error which I keep having says, literally, "Intercambiador with this Dni already exists"
I have looked everywhere in the project but I haven't found the reason
(Yes, I know that some parts may be useless or could be improved, thank you for your feedback)
I expected to "instantiate" (my excuses, new to Django, I don't have the clear definition) a user when the credentials were correct
I keep having an error which I have not declared in the validation

Try to read the error message, basically it has everything in it.
The problem is that you have defined your database model like this:
class Intercambiador(AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager):

opciones_estado = (('suspendido', 'Suspendido'), ('activo', 'Activo'))

dni = models.PositiveIntegerField(primary_key=True, editable=True, unique=True)
contrasenia = models.CharField(max_length=30),
# something else

The DNI column is a primary key for your model, also it is unique. When you define your model like this, Django makes a table with column DNI when migrating the table. The unique=True part basically tells Django to create a database constraint for this field to be unique. It means that only one row could have a specific value for this column.
Basically you're trying to create a user with DNI value that is already exists in your table, that's why you're getting this exception.
Also, you have defined DNI field as primary key AND editable (which means you could modify your PK). I would not suggest to use this approach, only if you know what you're doing. PK's should be stable as possible, even if DB engine allows you to update them.
I suggest you to read Django documentation section about databases and how it works internally, it would save you a lot of time. Hope it helps.

I get what you say and I'll have a look at that. But exactly which part of my code am I creating a new user? Does a form in django only works as a mean to "create"?

The problem is in this line: cleaned_data = super().clean()
Take a look at ModelForm docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-clean-method

Thank you so much. This was the cause. Have a great day!
